# Crash when exporting rapidjson::Document as string

Tags: rapidjson

My code is like this:

```
rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.SetObject();

// insert some sub JsonObjects
rapidjson::Document subA;
if (!subA.Parse<0>(jsonStringA->c_str()).HasParseError()) {
    doc.AddMember("A", subA, doc.GetAllocator());
}

rapidjson::Document subB;
if (!subB.Parse<0>(jsonStringB->c_str()).HasParseError()) {
    doc.AddMember("B", subB, doc.GetAllocator());
}

// Export document as string
rapidjson::StringBuffer buf;
rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buf);
doc.Accept(writer);
buffer.GetString();
```

Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) produced after called `buffer.GetString();`

And the abort message is:

```
/document.h:1778: bool rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::Accept(Handler &) const [Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<char>, Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, Handler = rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0>]: assertion "m->name.IsString()" failed'
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code.

And if i replace "`rapidjson::Document subA`" with "`rapidjson::Document subA(doc.GetAllocator())`",
this issue appears to be resolved. But i don't know why.

Comment: Where is your buffer coming from? Should it be buf?